# Publish a Platform Event From Within a Platform Event Apex Trigger - Question

Tags: trigger, platform-event, transaction

My scenario is the following:

1. an Opportunity is updated
2. for some updates, the Opportunity before update trigger needs to update one or more OpportunityLineItems. The before update trigger cannot do the updates directly (exceptions are thrown); the trigger therefore publishes a Platform Event `UpdateLinitems__e` with publish behaviour `Publish After Commit`.
3. the `UpdateLineItems__e` after insert trigger updates the line items based on the information in the event.
4. next, the `UpdateLineItems__e` after insert trigger publishes a Platform Event `UIRefresh__e` which will be handled by a VF page. The VF page rerenders the entire page or parts thereof.

**The Question is:** what is the correct publish behavior setting for the `UIRefresh__e` event?

I guess the answer depends on whether or not we are in a transaction while the `UpdateLineItems__e` trigger is executing and / or on what happens when an event is published with behavior `Publish After Commit` when there is no current transaction.

- when the `UpdateLinitems__e` trigger is executing within a transaction, the event must certainly be published after commit, otherwise the event might be consumed before the commit.
- when the `UpdateLinitems__e` trigger is not executing within a transaction I need to know what happens when I publish `UIRefresh__e` with `Publish After Commit` outside of a transaction context. For instance, when not in a transaction, is `Publish After Commit` the same as `Publish Immediately` ? That is, when in doubt, I can always use `Publish After Commit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having got into a mess using `Publish Immediately`, generally I recommend using `Publish After Commit`.

The "mess" for me was that the event publishing transaction's changed data is invisible to other transactions until it commits. So code subscribing to a `Publish Immediately` event from that transaction that needs to present or otherwise process that transactions changed data can't see the changes because it is running before the commit.

Answer (score 4):

All consumption of Platform Events is done in a separate transaction, regardless of `Publish Immediately` or `Publish After Commit`. Platform Events are published asynchronously.

The distinction between the two publishing behaviors is merely whether you want the event to be published before or after the publisher's transaction commits.

So, your choice for the VF page (and the trigger that publishes for it) is whether you want the VF page to display data that might or might not be rolled back.

Comment: cropredy - can you please clarify further: what are the UIRefresh__e publisher's transaction boundaries? coterminous with the UpdateLineItem__e trigger context? does it matter whether `update lineItems` is done before `publish refreshEvent` or the other way around, assuming publish behaviour is `Publish After Commit`?

Comment: `UI_refreshEvent`'s transaction boundary starts as soon as it is consumed. It may overlap the publisher's transaction boundary if published immediately or will always follow the publisher's transaction boundary if published after commit.